# AdMob displays status to Inactive

Tags: java, android, admob

I added two apps on my AdMob account. One because Green and active right away and the second is still displayed Red and inactive.

Is it because there is a wait for 24 hours to refresh?

I checked my publisher ID and they are both different and correct on the app.

I can see the ads on the phone and it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inactive just means that it hasn't recorded any traffic for that app.
It doesn't mean that you still need to verified or are being blocked.